# What is a bimodal or multimodal space rocket engine? Especially a nuclear-powered one?

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design, nuclear-pulse-propulsion

I can't seem to find a specific answer anywhere....

I wonder if it means using the radioactive fuel to power the electronic equipment, purely via natural decay, but also using the same fuel to power a fission reactor-based engine (thrust)....

Or, perhaps, another 'mode' is detonating an actual small atomic bomb for extra thrust?      Or.... fusion is involved?

Comment: Can you post a link? It's hard to know exactly what you are asking.

Comment: ...what research have you done? I'm struggling to figure out how you got to the Orion interpretation, let alone fusion, or why you'd build a system that incorporates a reactor but is limited to decay heat.